# Issue with Open Graph Debugger not seeing product:sale_price:currency

Tags: php, debugging, facebook-opengraph

I'm having an issue trying to verify my Open Graph object. The debugger says:

> Errors That Must Be Fixed: Object Missing a Required Value
>
> "Object at URL
>   'http://www.secondhandcars.co.za/detail.php?item_id=5077' of type
>   'product' is invalid because a required property
>   'product:price:currency' of type 'string' was not provided."

Yet in the section of Open Graph Information I see this:

```
<meta property="product:sale_price:currency" content="ZAR" />
```

Am I just missing something? I Followed the example to the letter only changes my currency from USD to ZAR I even changed it to the RAND Value R.

Answer (score 0):

**product:price** and **product:sale_price** are different fields.

If you use **product:price** field, you should define **product:price:currency** and **product:price:amount** values together.

```
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="100.00" />
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="ZAR" />
```

This rule also applies to **product:sale_price** field.

```
<meta property="product:sale_price:amount" content="90.00" />
<meta property="product:sale_price:currency" content="ZAR" />
```